# SendReliableMessage vs. SendUnreliableMessage Google Play RTM

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer

I implemented Google Play Services to my simple real time multiplayer game (RTM). The game works quiet good - but now I get to a point I need more "proof" data connectivity.

My problem explained: I send positioning data (XY-values of the sprites) via unreliableMessage and when a player is shooting, these information will send via reliableMessage. This enables me to implement a "force to shoot"-logic if a "shot-message" isn't correctly send (get truncated, lost etc).

Now I want to send values to the other device which handles a advanced shooting logic. So sprites should be able to shoot in an angular and not only straightforward. At this point I can't use my "force to shoot"-logic (which represents only a boolean "shot" or "not shot") - I need to send more data in a trusted way. I really break my head about this problem for hours but I don't get any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:
The reality shows that my doubts doesn't really matter. **So I only update my sprites' position- and rotation-data** and in this situation I'm able to shoot by my already implemented game-logic... It works exact and fine. :)